# operator + overload question

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Why does this code give the error message "IntelliSense: too many parameters for this operator function"

```
int operator+(PerfectNum a,PerfectNum b)
{
    return (a.thenum+b.thenum);
}
```

PerfectNum is a regular class, and thenum is an int.
This method is in the class.

Comment: This is not a class method is it?  If you make it a method of PerfectNum, then you need just one parameter and use "this.thenum" as the other.

Comment: Is that the exact error message you get from the compiler? Function `int operator+ (PerfectNum, PerfectNum)` returns too many parameters?

Comment: No compiler will produce such an error message. Please use copy and paste when posting compiler output here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're defining this as a member function, right?

In that case, the left hand side is simply `*this`:

```
// .h
class PerfectNum
{
    public:
    int operator+(PerfectNum other) const;
};

// .cpp
int PerfectNum::operator+(const PerfectNum &other) const
{
    return this->thenum + other.thenum;
}
```

Comment: Kind of wrong. The operator should be a free function, possibly a friend. If it is a member, it should be const. And the parameter should proably be a const reference. And the syntax is wrong - the implementation is missing a return type. Who is voting this stuff up?

Comment: Oops. You're right, this is all terrible. I had a pretty stressful work day yesterday and I needed to escape from it, but obviously I left some of my knowledge behind :-)

Comment: Also: I see no reason this can't be a member function. I might be missing some knowledge. Please *help me out* rather than just criticize everything, if that is the case. I assumed it should be a member function because *it would explain why there are too many parameters* (per the OP's error message).

Comment: It should not be a member function so that conversions can be performed on both left and right operands. operator+ in C++ is almost *never* implemented as a member function, because of this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make your operator a non-member function.

Comment: +1 Sheesh. With all those up-votes for the incorrect answer and only one for your correct answer, I felt compelled to up-vote here. And everyone else who answered this correctly.

Comment: Could I have a good, solid explanation for why it should not be a member function? I was taught that it was okay when you wanted to restrict it to be a `PerfectNum` on the left-hand side; since the OP only wants it to be between two `PerfectNum` objects, I figured a member function was the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Operator+ should be non-member function. The return type should be const object. If you have operator= defined, then it is always better to have operator+= defined as well. So, you can implement operator+ in terms of operator+=.

```
const PerfectNum operator+(const PerfectNum& lhs, const PerfectNum& rhs)
{
     PerfectNum ret(lhs);
     ret += rhs;
     return rhs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overloading operator + certainly should not be a friend/free function when declared as a class method.  Here's a very simple implementation:

```
class PerfectNum {
    public:
        PerfectNum(int);
        PerfectNum(const PerfectNum&);
        PerfectNum operator+(const PerfectNum&) const;
    private:
        int mNumber;
};

PerfectNum PerfectNum::operator+(const PerfectNum& rhs) const
{
    return PerfectNum(this->mNumber + rhs.mNumber);
}
```